# How to parse JSON file with different node

Tags: c#, json, parsing

i am working in C#,where I created one small project.In the project I am parsing one json file.I just want to ask that can I parse or use the json file like.....

**JSON File**

```
{
"Nodes": [
      {
        "Number of Location":"4",
      },
      {
        "longitude": "22.3 ",
        "latitude": "45.3",
        "Demand": "5"
      },
      {
        "longitude": "26.3 ",
        "latitude": "46.3",
        "Demand": "6"
      },
      {
        "longitude": "35.1 ",
        "latitude": "48.2",
        "Demand": "2"
      }
]
}
```

**C# code**

```
 string path = null;
 Console.WriteLine("enter the path where order matrix is loacated");
 path = Console.ReadLine();
 System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
 string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();
 JObject o = JObject.Parse(myString);
 Console.WriteLine(o["Nodes"][0]["Number of Location"]);
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(o["Nodes"][i+1]["longitude"]);
     Console.WriteLine(o["Nodes"][i+1]["latitude"]);
     Console.WriteLine(o["Nodes"][i+1]["Demand"]);
 }
```

I am not getting the value of **Number of location** when i am parsing the JSON file.so can you help that how can I fetch the value of n**umber of location.**.

Comment: Are you getting a `null` value?

Comment: No,actually when I am getting string from the file then that string doesn't contain the "Number of Location" field but all the renaming field is fetching.

Comment: What does the field contains or prints out? May you post it here?

Comment: I believe it is because of the spaces in the "Number of location"

Comment: the `json` is not valid.The `Array` seems invalid.

Comment: yeah it is not there should be no comma in this line "Number of Location":"4", therefore using JsonConvert won't work , the solution is to combine jobject with jarray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should be using JArray to parse a json Array , the code would look like this :

```
        var res = JObject.Parse(text)["Nodes"];
        foreach (var o in res.Children<JObject>())
        {
            foreach (var property in o.Properties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " " + property.Value);
            }
        }
```

if you want just the number of location use this:

```
        var res = JObject.Parse(text)["Nodes"];
        Console.WriteLine(res[0]["Number of Location"]);
```

Comment: Its not an array its an object.

Comment: He pasted the whole file. It is literally an object with a single property of type array. But a naked property is not a valid top level JSON structure. Anyway, the you don't need to call ```JArray.Parse``` because the property has already been desearilized into a JArray by the call to ```JObject.Parse```.

Comment: No the result of JObject.Parse is a JObject not a JArray

Comment: Your code parses the file into a JObject, uses the indexer to access the Nodes property which is of type JArray, re-serializes that JArray by calling ToString, and then parses it back into a JArray. Just write this: ```var res =(JArray)JObject.Parse(text)["Nodes"]```

Comment: in what way this code is different than mine,,, you said Jobject.Parse(text) is a JArray when actually it s not,, anyway I ll just take away the JArray.Parse , to make the code simpler

Comment: friends,when i am fetching the string from the JSON file then that string doesnot containg the **number of loaction**.and if string doesnot contain then how can i Parse it

Comment: Show us the json in your file then , if a field doesn't exist you just can't parse something that doesn't exist ,, the first solution will print outt all the existing properties and their values